# ASP.net feedback form

Tags: asp.net, survey

i want to implement a sort of feedback form/survey form in asp.net which is linked to a database. can any one help on any good tutorials or articles

i want to create a asp.net application which will take questions from a database then display them on the form. once the user has finished the survey the results will be stored into the database.

can any one help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/learn  is the first place you should go.

There is a wealth of videos, tutorials, and documentation.

Look for the beginner videos.

**Edit**

They changed their site.  I'd start here:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/

and go here later
http://www.asp.net/mvc/

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with an ASP.NET MVC application.

Take a look at the [ASP.NET MVC Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/mvc/).